# php POST from html form, but can not get data

Tags: php, html, sql

---

*

Im trying to make a Register page. But the POST in php can not get any data from form in html page. If I ran the code. The raw in data base is created but doesn't have any data inside. PLease Help!

## *

**My insert.php**

```
    $firstname=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST ['firstname']);
$lastname=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST ['lastname']);
$pw=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST ['pw']));
  $pw2=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST ['pw2']));
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST ['email']);
$mobile=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST ['mobile']);
$address=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST ['address']);
$postcode=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST ['postcode']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    echo $sql;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

**My form in html:**

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">

        <div class="login-img"><img src="images/register-ico.png"></div>
        <div class="login-form">
            <label><i></i><p>Email Address<span class="required"> *</span></p></label>
            <input class="login-input" name='email' id="email" type="text" placeholder="harry@boei.co.nz">
            <label><i></i><p>First Name<span class="required"> *</span></p></label>
            <input class="login-input" name='firstname' id="firstname" type="text">
            <label><i></i><p>Last Name</p></label>
            <input class="login-input" name ='lastname'id="lastname" type="tel">
            <label><i></i><p>Password<span class="required"> *</span></p></label>
            <input class="login-input" name='pw'id="password" type="email">
            <label><i></i><p>Re-enter Password<span class="required"> *</span></p></label>
            <input class="login-input" 'name'='pw2' id="password2" type="text">
            <label><i></i><p>Mobile</p></label>
            <input class="login-input" name='mobile'id="mobile" type="text">
            <label><i></i><p>Delivery Address</p></label>
            <input class="login-input" name='address'id="address" type="text">
            <label><i></i><p>Postcode</p></label>
            <input class="login-input" name='postcode'id="postcode" type="text">
            <div class="step-required"><span class="required"> * required field</span></div>


            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>

        </div>

        <div class="register-info">
            <input name="reg" type="reg"  value="reg">
            <div class="register-text"><p>By Registering, you agree to accept our <br><a href="terms.html">Terms and Conditions</a> and <a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>.</p></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: $_POST not $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Comment: Just a heads up, you have a probable typo `emial` in this line `$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ['emial']);`

Comment: I have changed $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA to $_POST, But still not get any data.

Comment: now add `var_dump($_POST);` is it populated?

Comment: Nop.Not in database, but It returns like this:

Comment: `array(9) { ["email"]=> string(17) "email@address.com" ["firstname"]=> string(8) "Input@FN" ["lastname"]=> string(8) "Input@LN" ["pw"]=> string(8) "Input@PW" ["mobile"]=> string(7) "Input@M" ["address"]=> string(13) "Input@Address" ["postcode"]=> string(8) "Input@PC" ["submit"]=> string(6) "submit" ["reg"]=> string(3) "reg" } `

Comment: well their are your values

Comment: But database still empty. And the `echo $sql;` prints `INSERT INTO user (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email) VALUES ('', '', '')`

Comment: oh I'm blind, mostly because i don't use such a dated db API anymore (hint), but `mysqli_real_escape_string` requires 2 arguments, your missing one, read the manual to find out which

Comment: Oh yeah, It fixed after I read the manual. Thank you so much ->rtfm

Comment: please post schema of database and database error.  note - you don't show open connection to database, it is possible that $conn is null

Answer (score 0):

what is your PHP version? HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0 and it's just getting raw POST data.

- HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA it should be $_POST.
- You are typing 'Email' incorrectly in post parameters.

Comment: It is php7.0    I fixed $_POST, and the email typing, but still not getting any data.

Answer (score 0):

declare mysql connection

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

and it should be something like

```
$firstname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]);
```

and if you want a procedure type

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($SQLConnection, $_POST["firstname"]);
```